# Which method(s) in UIViewController is called only once, when the view is first presented? viewDidLoad?

Tags: iphone, ios, viewdidload

Which method(s) in UIViewController is called only once, when the view is first presented?

The reason I'm asking is I need to call the addObserver method of NSNotificationCenter, and I only need to do it once And, I don't need to call removeObserver when the view goes out of sight. (Actually, I do some light processing when a notification is received when the view is out of sight.)

What is the best practice - what method should I call? 
Is it viewDidLoad method - can anyone confirm if this method is called only ONCE and never called when the view appears subsequently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a view controller allocates its resources programmatically, create a custom initialization method that is specific to your view controller. This method should call the super class’s init method and then perform any class specific initialization.

In general, do not write complex initialization methods. Instead, implement a simple initialization method and then provide properties for clients of your view controller to configure its behaviors.

2 steps,

- The view controller calls its loadView method
- If the view controller is associated with a storyboard, it loads the
  views from the storyboard. If the view controller is not associated
  with a storyboard, an empty UIView object is created and assigned to
  the view property.

The view controller calls its viewDidLoad method, which enables your subclass to perform any additional load-time tasks.

this diagram can give you a better idea

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
-(id)initWithNibName - or -
-(id)init
```

will be called only once in any condition

As far as `viewDidLoad` is concerned it also gets called once but can get triggered once memory warnings are received (not for iOS 6 though).viewDidLoad of a controller gets called after the viewDidUnload is triggered because of memory overload.

Answer (score 1):

For observers, even under ARC, start observing in one of the initialiser methods, awake from nib, or viewDidLoad, and unregister for observations in the `dealloc` method

Answer (score 0):

Yes `- (void)viewDidLoad` method is first call at the time view is loading process and        -`(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method is call at the time of view will presenting process

But if you want create method that call at **once** then use GLOBALIZATION of method 
by `-(id)init` it will call only once time .

Comment: The problem here is initWithNibName:bundle: is called. So, in this case if I put it in init, will it be called?

Comment: creaste custom method and it call in -(id)init method, so this custom method call at once. And in custom method  write code that you want.